# how to measure the RSSI strength signal between peers using wifi direct?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, networking, linux, wifi-direct

there is no feature to measure the `RSSI` between peers in Wifi-direct, so how to get `RSSI` between them.

actually i go under API for WIFI to see how they measure WIFI `RSSI` So i see that they send Command as parameter to native method, but i can't catch this command!!!

in this method `wifi_send_command` in **wifi.c** from this [link](http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/hardware/libhardware_legacy/wifi/wifi.c#wifi_send_command).

as i know Android is under linux, the `iwconfig` is linux command to get the wireless information interface, if i used it can i get the Wifi direct information ? or it is just return the access points network information?

anyone have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information inside **wpa_cli**. Open wpa_cli in wifi-direct interface and do a **scan** and **scan_results** as below.

```
adb shell wpa_cli -i<wifi-direct interface name> -p<socket path> scan
adb shell wpa_cli -i<wifi-direct interface name> -p<socket path> scan_results
```

You will get small info about connected peer(device address, channel,rssi etc). Hope this works!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131539/discussion-on-answer-by-rilwan-how-to-measure-the-rssi-strength-signal-between-p).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the RSSI between 2 peers before connection, just try:

- In linux under wpa_supplicant

  ```
  sudo wpa_cli p2p_peer 74:da:3f:58:5c:f0
  ```

  (where 74:da:3f:58:5c:f0 is the MAC address of the second peer.)
- In Android, it should be something like this (guessed and untested)

  ```
  adb shell wpa_cli -i <wifi-direct interface name> -p <socket path> p2p_peer 74:da:3f:58:5c:f0
  ```

After that you will get a big string. Then search for the word Level (the RSSI comes in dBm).

Answer (score 0):

For non-rooted devices try the following:

Device A: Linux
Device B: Android

1. Get the P2P group name of one device. This can be seen by using `wpa_cli` on the linux device.
   `<3>P2P-GROUP-STARTED p2p-wlan0-0 GO ssid="DIRECT-Gw" freq=2462 passphrase="Vz4GVojX" go_dev_addr=02:04:4b:e0:80:73`
2. Open an adb shell to the Android device.
3. Type:  `dumpsys | grep "DIRECT-Gw"`
4. Look at the output:

```
 - SSID: DIRECT-Gw, BSSID: 02:04:4b:e0:00:73, capabilities: [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][RSN-PSK-CCMP][ESS][WPS], level: -61, frequency: 2462, timestamp: 104993415063, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), passpoint: no, ChannelBandwidth: 0, cen
terFreq0: 2462, centerFreq1: 0, standard: 11n, 80211mcResponder: is not supported, Radio Chain Infos: []
```